# Replace custom SVG icons in Twenty Twenty-One

Tags: php, svg, theme-twenty-twenty-one

I was trying to investigate how to replace some icons of the parent theme with the child theme but I was not able to do it.
I am trying to replace the SVG icons that are in the twentytwentyone\classes\class-twenty-twenty-one-svg-icons.php file, specifically the Menu and Close icons.
In my child theme I created the classes folder and copied the same svg icons file, but when I try to call it in my child theme functions.php, it doesn't work, I'm probably using the wrong functions.

**class-twenty-twenty-one-svg-icons.php file parent theme**

```
class Twenty_Twenty_One_SVG_Icons {

/**
 * User Interface icons – svg sources.
 *
 * @since Twenty Twenty-One 1.0
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected static $icons = array(
    'arrow_right' => '<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="m4 13v-2h12l-4-4 1-2 7 7-7 7-1-2 4-4z" fill="currentColor"/></svg>',
    'arrow_left'  => '<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M20 13v-2H8l4-4-1-2-7 7 7 7 1-2-4-4z" fill="currentColor"/></svg>',
    /*Change menu icon. I would have to change it in ChildTheme*/
    // 'menu'        => '<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M4.5 6H19.5V7.5H4.5V6ZM4.5 12H19.5V13.5H4.5V12ZM19.5 18H4.5V19.5H19.5V18Z" fill="currentColor"/></svg>',
    // 'close'       => '<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M12 10.9394L5.53033 4.46973L4.46967 5.53039L10.9393 12.0001L4.46967 18.4697L5.53033 19.5304L12 13.0607L18.4697 19.5304L19.5303 18.4697L13.0607 12.0001L19.5303 5.53039L18.4697 4.46973L12 10.9394Z" fill="currentColor"/></svg>',
    'close'       => '<svg viewBox="0 0 36 26" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="currentColor" points="29.4,1.7 28.8,1.1 17.5,12.4 6.2,1.1 5.6,1.7 16.9,13 5.6,24.3 6.2,24.9 17.5,13.6 28.8,24.9 29.4,24.3 18.1,13 "/></svg>',
    'menu'        => '<svg viewBox="0 0 36 26" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M1,1.3h34v0.8H1V1.3z M1,12.4h34v0.8H1V12.4z M34.9,23.8H1v0.9h34v-0.9H34.9z" fill="currentColor"/></svg>',
    'plus'        => '<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M18 11.2h-5.2V6h-1.6v5.2H6v1.6h5.2V18h1.6v-5.2H18z" fill="currentColor"/></svg>',
    'minus'       => '<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M6 11h12v2H6z" fill="currentColor"/></svg>',
);
```

As you can see, for the moment I'm replacing it in the parent theme, but that's not the idea.

**class-twenty-twenty-one-child-svg-icons.php my custom svg icons**

```
class Twenty_Twenty_One_Child_SVG_Icons {

/**
 * User Interface icons – svg sources.
 *
 * @since Twenty Twenty-One 1.0
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected static $icons = array(
    'arrow_right' => '<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="m4 13v-2h12l-4-4 1-2 7 7-7 7-1-2 4-4z" fill="currentColor"/></svg>',
    'arrow_left'  => '<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M20 13v-2H8l4-4-1-2-7 7 7 7 1-2-4-4z" fill="currentColor"/></svg>',
    'close'       => '<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M12 10.9394L5.53033 4.46973L4.46967 5.53039L10.9393 12.0001L4.46967 18.4697L5.53033 19.5304L12 13.0607L18.4697 19.5304L19.5303 18.4697L13.0607 12.0001L19.5303 5.53039L18.4697 4.46973L12 10.9394Z" fill="currentColor"/></svg>',
    'menu'        => '<svg viewBox="0 0 36 26" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M1,1.3h34v0.8H1V1.3z M1,12.4h34v0.8H1V12.4z M34.9,23.8H1v0.9h34v-0.9H34.9z" fill="currentColor"/></svg>',
    'plus'        => '<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M18 11.2h-5.2V6h-1.6v5.2H6v1.6h5.2V18h1.6v-5.2H18z" fill="currentColor"/></svg>',
    'minus'       => '<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M6 11h12v2H6z" fill="currentColor"/></svg>',
);
```

**My functions trying to call the custom svg icons in functions.php**

```
function include_extra_svg() {
require_once get_theme_file_path( 'classes/class-twenty-twenty-one-child-svg-icons.php' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_extra_svg' );
```

I hope I have explained well, I would be very grateful to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how that file works, and including it will just load the class definition, it won't create a `Twenty_Twenty_One_Child_SVG_Icons`  object or override `Twenty_Twenty_One_SVG_Icons`. It's also not how child themes work. Child themes let you override templates specifically, not arbitrary files and classes.

Instead, use the `twenty_twenty_one_svg_icons_{$group}` filters to modify the array in your child theme. The filter is the best option. For example the to filter the `social` icons use the `twenty_twenty_one_svg_icons_social` filter in `functions.php`:

```php
add_filter( 'twenty_twenty_one_svg_icons_social', 'yache_modify_svg_icons' );
function yache_modify_svg_icons( array $social_icons ) : array {
    // modify/add/replace $social_icons here
    $social_icon['500px'] = 'the new 500px inline svg tags';
    return $social_icons;
}
```

The main icon groups are `social` and `ui`, `ui` will contain the `menu` and `close` options, much like `social` contains`the`500px`and`twitter` options.

If you want to modify the URLs, you will also need to filter `twenty_twenty_one_social_icons_map` so it detects new social network URLs you add.

Note that this is separate from the social/etc icons block in the block editor which use a different system unrelated to this functionality.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the answer!
I tried to do it this way
function mychildtheme_twentytwenty_svg_icons ( $icons ){
 $icons['menu'] = 'mysvgcode';
note: I put mysvgcode to make the comment shorter

 return $icons;
}
add_filter( "twenty_twenty_one_svg_icons_{$group}", 'mychildtheme_twentytwenty_svg_icons');

but I am not doing it right, how should I do it to modify the svg menu icon? I don't know what hook_name I should put to add_filter

Comment: `{$group}` is a placeholder for the SVG icon group that contains the icon you want to modify, e.g. `twenty_twenty_one_svg_icons_social`, you're not meant to literally put `{$group}` in the filter name. In this case the `menu` icon is in the `ui` group

Comment: Great, it worked for me! Thank you very much!

Comment: Awesome! If this answered your question could you consider marking it as the correct answer by clicking the tick button under the votes?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; it just gives a clue

Comment: @popnoodles this isn't a copy paste answer, it tells exactly you what you need to do but it does it in prose, not copy pasta examples. I have made some adjustments to clarify things that changed since such as the block editor, but you will need to read and understand the answer